# dpkg linux headers dependencies error while upgrading the linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, linux-headers

I am using ubuntu 20 right now, from the last few days the software updater is popping up with some updates that need to be installed and when I click to install it starts the installation process but after some time I get this error"The installation or removal of a software package failed."

when I try to update using terminal I get this error

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-77
 linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

so I tried installing Linux headers but the same error keep showing up

please help me with this.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-77 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup err
or from a previous failure.
                           dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of l
inux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-77; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-77 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-hwe-18
.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-headers-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup e
rror from a previous failure.
                             No apport report written because MaxReports is rea
ched already
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No ap
port report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                         ependency problems - l
eaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 5.4.0.77.80); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-generic; however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-77
 linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

ps:I don't understand what are linux headers and I don't know very much of the os concept as well, so please try to add commands how to implement your answer

Comment: Check your repository list.

Comment: could you please tell me how to list them?

Comment: The output of the command `inxi -r` will list the configuration files and the repos referenced in them.

Answer (score 0):

You are use Ubuntu 20.04 but (for example) installing `linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04`

Check your list of repositories - is it a mixture of 18.04 and 20.04?

Comment: `  5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1        5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1    5.0.0-29.31~18.04.1   5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2    5.0.0-36.39~18.04.1    5.3.0-53.47~18.04.1                                         5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1  5.3.0-61.55~18.04.1    5.3.0-62.56~18.04.1   5.4.0-42.46~18.04.1                                         5.4.0-45.49~18.04.2     5.4.0-47.51~18.04.1` these are kernels i got in my system

Comment: You have too many kernels. You can only use one at at a time. Since they all have 18.04 appended to their names, I'm guessing that you are running Ubuntu 18.04? You have to follow the proper upgrade procedure if you want to use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: no i am using  20.04, i donno why its showing all 18.04 appended.